# How do I create a bash script to allow me to log into multiple clients on a network without having me enter the password everytime?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm on my network but want to be able to quickly log onto multiple clients on it without having to type SSH username@ipaddress everytime and then be prompted for a password. They all have the same password, is there a way for this to be automated? tips and knowledge are greatly appreciated

Comment: You might set up passwordless login to remote hosts using script ssh-copy-id.

Comment: Additionally, you can add common hosts to your `.ssh/config` file, along with the appropriate user name, so you only have to type `ssh foo` instead of `ssh foouser@fooaddress`. Read (or skim, to start) `man ssh_config` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

ssh-keygen

will create your public/private key pair in the ~/.ssh directory.   You can enter  for every prompt.  Please be aware that you should not share ~/.ssh/id_rsa (the generated private key) with anyone.  Consider it your password.

The following command will upload your public key to each host in question:

```
ssh-copy-id username@ipaddress
```

The above command copies your ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (the public key) to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote box.  You will be prompted for your password, but that should be the last time.

Once you have copied your public key, you should be able to log in after that without a password.

```
ssh username@ipaddress
```